# Why is the probe function in my kernel module not being called?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

While following, among others, this tutorial ([1](http://tali.admingilde.org/linux-docbook/writing_usb_driver.pdf)) and reading certain chapters in the *Linux Device Drivers* book, I cannot get the `pr_debug()` statements in the probe function to show any output in dmesg.

Here's my code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>    /*included for all kernel modules*/
#include <linux/kernel.h>    /*included for KERN_DEBUG*/
#include <linux/init.h>      /*included for __init and __exit macros*/
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

#define VENDOR_ID 0x0930
#define DEVICE_ID 0x6545

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("dev");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("eusb driver");

static struct usb_device_id eusb_table[] = {
        { USB_DEVICE(VENDOR_ID, DEVICE_ID) },
        { } /* Terminating entry */
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, eusb_table);

static int eusb_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
        pr_debug("USB probe function called\n");
        return 0;
}

static void eusb_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
        pr_debug("USB disconnect function called\n");
}

static struct usb_driver eusb_driver = {
    //.owner =  THIS_MODULE,
    .name =     "eusb",
    .probe =    eusb_probe,
    .disconnect =   eusb_disconnect,
    .id_table =     eusb_table
};

static int __init eusb_init(void)
{
    int result = 0;

    pr_debug("Hello world!\n");
    result = usb_register(&eusb_driver);
    if(result){
        pr_debug("error %d while registering usb\n", result);}
    else{pr_debug("no error while registering usb\n");}

    return 0;
}

static void __exit eusb_exit(void)
{
    usb_deregister(&eusb_driver);
    pr_debug("Exiting module\n");
}

module_init(eusb_init);
module_exit(eusb_exit);
```

and *Makefile*:

```make
obj-m := eusb.o
CFLAGS_eusb.o := -DDEBUG
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Make finishes without errors, after `insmod` I can see the module listed in `lsmod` and the `pr_debug()` in the init and exit functions show output in dmesg.

When inserting the device however the probe function seems to not get called (or the `pr_debug()` statements do not show any output in dmesg).

Dmesg output:

```
[ 7777.521236] Hello world!
[ 7777.521264] usbcore: registered new interface driver eusb
[ 7777.521266] no error while registering usb
[ 7780.597087] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 7797.686970] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 7797.857324] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6545
[ 7797.857328] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7797.857330] usb 1-6: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
[ 7797.857331] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 7797.857333] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 08606E6D407FED10571E5067
[ 7797.858787] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7797.858902] scsi host11: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[ 7798.931417] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 7798.931824] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 7800.184749] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] 60964864 512-byte logical blocks: (31.2 GB/29.0 GiB)
[ 7800.186338] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 7800.186343] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 7800.187948] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 7800.187952] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 7800.220477]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[ 7800.225068] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 7802.798403] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 7802.799507] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

I have tried with another device, tried with `printk()` instead of `pr_debug()`. I found several questions on SO with the same problem, but my code is as far as I can tell almost/completely the same as the code in the answers.

I have also tried with:

```c
USB_INTERFACE_INFO(
        USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID,
        USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
    USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD)
```

instead of `USB_DEVICE()` (the other device was a keyboard).

I noticed that some answers talk about platform_driver instead of usb_driver, but I think this is not relevant for me, as it is never mentioned in the tutorials.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your purpose just educational? Otherwise the driver is already there and it's called `usb-storage`. Seems even that driver enumerates your device first. Try to disable `usb-storage` and load your driver again. Or better use the virtual machine (KVM / Qemu) to try your drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, just educational. I couldn't find the usb-storage module listed in lsmod, however it did get loaded on insertion of the usb device apparently and prevented my module from being used, like you said. I used usb-storage.blacklist=yes and uas.blacklist=yes (not sure this 2nd one was necessary, but it got loaded together with usb-storage) at grub command line before boot to temporarily disable them and now it used my module before loading those.  How do I mark your response as answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your purpose just educational? Otherwise the driver is already there and it's called `usb-storage`. Seems even that driver enumerates your device first. Try to disable `usb-storage` and load your driver again. Or better use the virtual machine (KVM / Qemu) to try your drivers.

Comment: How to test driver using qemu virtulisation?

Comment: @shashankarora It depends on the driver/hardware. Virtualization environments, such as QEMU, may or may not have the necessary hardware emulation, so for some cases it might be needed to develop that first.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your `Hello world!` was printed which implies the module was loaded successfully. Often all the modules claiming to handle the device via `usb_device_id*` table are loaded. See [9.3.2.3. Module Loading](https://web.archive.org/web/20201123223955/https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter09/udev.html).

Now, the probe function is called only for the driver the device was *bound* to. In the case where there is no priority set and two drivers are capable of binding, any of them might get the first opportunity.

I have written a [blog post](https://m47r1x.github.io/posts/driver-loading-and-binding/) which might clear things further (if not, do comment here).

Further, you might want to go through these two relevant mailing list threads

- https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-October/003639.html
- https://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=162123892329464&w=2